# Prove $D$ is uncountable.

Tags: real-analysis

> Suppose $E\subset \Bbb{R} $ is uncountable, let $D=\{x \in E \mid \forall \delta \gt0,(x-\delta,x+\delta)\cap E$ is uncountable$ \}$. Now  Prove $D$ is uncountable.

To prove $D$ is uncountable, we can prove $E\backslash D$ is at most countable. For any $x\in E\backslash D$, by the definition of $D$ , there exists $\delta\gt0$ such that $(x-\delta,x+\delta)\cap E$ is at most countable. Now I can't move forward any more. Thanks in advance for your hints.

Comment: Take $x\in D$. We have $B_{\delta}(x)\cap E \subset D$, for some $\delta>0$.

Comment: Make sure to show that $D$ is non-empty.

Comment: @Mr. X I get a little bit hard to understand why $B_{\delta}(x)\cap E \subset D$, could you explain more?

Comment: I deemed it easier, but this is my bit: assume by contradiction that the subset relationship does not hold for any $\delta>0$. Then, for any $\delta>0$, one can choose $y\in C_{\delta}\overset{\Delta}=B_{\delta}(x)\cap E$ and $y\notin D$. In other words, for any $y\in C_{\delta}$ there exists, $\epsilon(y)>0$ so that $B_{\epsilon(y)}(y)\cap E$ is countable. Now, we have, $C_{\delta}(x)\overset{\Delta}=B_{\delta}(x)\cap E= \bigcup_{y\in C_{\delta}} B_{\epsilon(y)}(y)\cap C_{\delta}(x)\subset \bigcup_{y\in C_{\delta}} B_{\epsilon(y)}(y)\cap \overline{C}_{\delta}(x)=$ (to be continued)

Comment: Since $\overline{C}_{\delta}(x)$ is compact, we have $\bigcup_{y\in C_{\delta}} B_{\epsilon(y)}(y)\cap \overline{C}_{\delta}(x)= \bigcup_{y\in C_{\delta}\cap R} B_{\epsilon(y)}(y)\cap \overline{C}_{\delta}(x)$ for some countable set $R$ -- any open cover of $\overline{C}_{\delta}(x)$ admits a finite open subcover. But each, $B_{\epsilon(y)}(y)\cap \overline{C}_{\delta}(x)$ is countable. This contradicts the fact that $x\in D$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my try:

1. Let $x\in E \backslash D$. Then for every $x\in E\backslash D$ there is $\delta_x > 0$ such that $O_x = (x-\delta_x, x+\delta_x) \cap E$ is at most countable.
2. Let $\mathcal{U}$ be a covering of $\mathbb{R}$ by open intervals. We can always choose a countable subcovering $\mathcal{U}' \subseteq \mathcal{U}$.
3. Thus $\{O_x \cap (E\backslash D) | x\in E\backslash D\}$ is an open covering of $E\backslash D$. $E\backslash D$ inherits property 2 from $\mathbb{R}$ and thus you find a countable covering of $E\backslash D$ consisting of sets $O_x \cap (E\backslash D)$.
4. Since $O_x \cap (E\backslash D)$ are countable and countable unions of countable sets yield countable sets we know $E\backslash D$ is countable.